# Why did I receive the Talkative badge? I've never participated in chat

Tags: support, badges, chat

To my surprise I received the [Talkative badge on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/884/talkative?userid=157882). It was described as follows:

> Posted 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

But I've never participated in chat. Is this related to the new *"continue this discussion in chat"* feature whenever comments exceed a certain size? I've indeed received some invitations for that, but I've always kindly declined to participate in chat and never clicked the chat link.

Why did I receive the badge then? Is this a bug? Does that chat invitation copy all existing comments into the chat or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is. You've "posted" 12 messages as the result of imported comments, the most recent of which [can be found on your chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc?tab=recent). I'm unable to locate the message that was starred, though. It's likely that it was in a room that was since removed.

Comment: "44 secs ago"?! I shake my fist at you, sir. And I can't find the starred message either.

Comment: Interesting. I was never been aware of that chat profile. But what do you think, was that badge fully deserved? In my humble opinion it is not. It was the system who copied/converted the comments, not me who participated in any chat. I'm also curious about that starred message.

Comment: I've peeked around in my chat profile, but where do you see that I've 12 messages? Where can I see all of those 12 messages? As to the starred one, perhaps it was converted from an upvoted comment?

Comment: @Chichiray I think you have a legitimate point, yeah. Of course, assuming that chat doesn't currently keep track of the fact that the messages were imported from comments, is it worth modifying to prevent a bronze badge? Perhaps not.

Comment: @Chichiray On your main chat profile page, the number in the bottom right corner represents your all-time message count, and the number in the bottom left corner represents your all-time room count. As for the starred message, I don't *think* it converts comment up votes to stars, but I'm not overly familiar with how it works. There's also no way currently to view all of your messages.

Comment: @Tim It doesn't (convert upvotes to stars, that is)

Comment: Thank you. Everything is clear now. I think they'll mark it "By Design" after all. It's just a bronze anyway.

Answer (score 6):

[Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103936/why-did-i-receive-the-talktative-badge-ive-never-participated-in-chat/103938#103938) has the right of it - you have messages being imported to chat.

The actual star was on a comment that was from an exchange over from this question:

[Figuring out why JSF getters are called when I don't expect them to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078477/figuring-out-why-jsf-getters-are-called-when-i-dont-expect-them-to-be-called)

The room was since deleted, but the event happened nonetheless, and within such time that you had 10 messages on chat. The message in question was:

> I see a `org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.ui.DebugPhaseListener` in your stacktrace. I don't use MyFaces, but this suggests that you've set project state to `Development` and that it is just precollecting some debug info based on the entire component tree for the case that the action fails later. Try `Production` instead and see if it still happens.

Comment: Thank you for finding the missing messages and the star. But I'm still curious as to how you found them. Can you please tell more?

Comment: @Chichiray A room created from a comment exchange is always entitled "Discussion Between A and B", for users A and B. I just searched for rooms that have 'BalusC' in their name, and as a moderator I can see deleted/frozen rooms.